# Get path from Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable Method in vb

Tags: vb.net, environment-variables, program-files

I am using visual basic and Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable Method and I want to get the path of Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(Program Files).How is that possible?
*I want to use that method instead of writing (C:/ProgramFiles), because some users  have Windows installed in D Drive.. I also want to get the path in textbox1.text .Thank's for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)
```

[SpecialFolder enumeration on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank's for your answer.But how will I change the text of textbox1? I have to something like..: textbox1.text = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) right?